# What are remote operations reported in "remoteOperationCount"?

Tags: hazelcast

One value exposed by Hazelcast through jmx and reported by the "Operation Service Information" is remoteOperationCount. Can anyone describe the meaning of this value?

We have seen this value go up from an average of <10 to close to 100 at the same time as response times have increased. I am unable to find a good description of this measurement online, which also means I am having a hard time figuring out why the increase happens, and whether problems are to be expected at ~100.

We run Hazelcast 3.11.1

Answer (score 0):

It's the number of pending invocations. So it's expected to increase in parallel with the response time. Both indicates that system is responding slower than the speed of incoming requests.